# Xamarin Prism Dry IoC service resolution error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, dryioc

I have a service I register and resolve in my application but it throws a lengthy error with some things I don't understand and I would appreciate anyone with experience using prism dry IoC to assist me with this problem.

#### Code throwing the error

```
//test 1 does not throw an error, this is a service in the ctor or test2 which causes the error
var test1 = ApplicationState.PrismContainer.GetService<ITestActionService>();

//test 2 throws an error when trying to be resolved and the cause is ITestActionService
var test2 = ApplicationState.PrismContainer.GetService<TestActionViewModel>();
```

#### The error

```
DryIoc.ContainerException: 'code: Error.UnableToResolveUnknownService;
message: Unable to resolve MyTestApp.Models.Actions.ITestActionService as parameter "actionService"
  in resolution root MyTestApp.ViewModels.Actions.TestActionViewModel {DryIoc.IfUnresolved.ReturnDefaultIfNotRegistered} FactoryId=204
  from container without scope
 with Rules with {TrackingDisposableTransients, UseDynamicRegistrationsAsFallbackOnly, FuncAndLazyWithoutRegistration, SelectLastRegisteredFactory} and without {ThrowOnRegisteringDisposableTransient, UseFastExpressionCompilerIfPlatformSupported}
 with FactorySelector=SelectLastRegisteredFactory
 with Made={FactoryMethod=ConstructorWithResolvableArguments}
Where no service registrations found
  and no dynamic registrations found in 1 of Rules.DynamicServiceProviders
  and nothing found in 0 of Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers'
```

#### TestActionViewModel Constructor

```
public TestActionViewModel (
            IDataStoreService dataStoreService,
            ITestActionService actionService,
            IMessagingService messagingService,
            IDialogService dialogService)
            : base(
                dataStoreService,
                actionService,
                messagingService,
                dialogService){}
```

Comment: That's strange, maybe @DanJSiegel at twitter or in the Prism repo issue can help you.

Comment: @dadhi do you mean create a new bug issue on the prism github repo?

Comment: Yes. Or better in the discussions and not in the issues.